# How to measure the memory used by a process at SIGABRT?

Tags: linux, process, memory

I run a long compilation that uses lots of memory. At a point it fails with SIGABRT. I would like to know how much memory is used then, before shutting down the process.

I use CentOS.

Is it possible by shell means to write a hook that is run before the process' memory is freed up by the operating system?